# Connection string not working on remote server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

I am working on a C# ASP.NET website that needs to connect to a database. I have all the connection strings set up and they work locally, but when I try to connect from the server I get an error that looks like this

```
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied]

[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server
```

The connection string:

```
<add name="Default" connectionString="Server=server;Database=database;User ID=user;Password=pass;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Would the app pool identity block the connection even when the username and password are supplied directly?

EDIT: There seems to be confusion about what my problem actually is. I can connect to the SQL server with the same connection string from my local ASP Development server just fine. The only issue is that I cannot connect to the SQL server from the production ASP server.

Comment: It seems like network connection issue - verify your remote sql server do accept remote connections and that the port 1433 is open on box where it is installed.

Comment: The sql server is not on my local machine, and I can connect to the sql instance from my machine. Would the sql server treat that connection different than the one c# is trying to create?

Comment: Yes, your credentials may not match among other things.

Comment: If you connect from your local computer to sql server, that says nothing about if your web server would be able to connect to the same sql server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You connections pool is not the problem -- you have a basic connectivity issue

You may have a bad connection string -- everything must be typed correctly -- you did not supply your actual credentials -- presumably for good reasons, unless this is your actual connection string, in which case you need to fix it with your correct connection settings)

You may be port blocked by a firewall whether personal, corporate, ISP, etc.

The DB may not be accepting network connections

The DB server may not be running

McAfee A/V has been known to cause problem.

I'm sure I have overlooked a few possible problems.

Comment: The connection string works on my local machine and I know it's running. McAfee isn't the problem as it is not running on the production server. The production server and the sql server are in the same network so if it were a firewall, it would have to be between the two servers. Which is unlikely, but I'll check it out.

Comment: I would first double check that the connection paramater (db, user, password) being used are exactly what you think they are -- write them out or debug to check them carefully.

Comment: Just checked again and the remote ASP server is using the correct connection string.

Comment: Test opening a db connection from another tool directly from web server using the same connection info.

Comment: There lies part of the problem in that I don't have direct access to the server. I do have other websites on the server connecting to the database, the only difference between those and this one is that this one is running in a different app pool. .NET version 4.0 on the new app pool and .NET 2.0 on the old app pool

Comment: An app pool does not really have anything to do with DB connections, it is a mechanism to isolate processes to issues from one website do not affect and unrelated website. I did not mention connection starving (running out of connections), but I seem to recall a different error message in this case.

Comment: Other than connection starving (usually do to failure to close connections, high traffic, and computationally heavy pages), I don't see why a different pool would be a problem all by itself -- again assuming nothing is misconfigured

Comment: Changing the app pool back to the old one allows it to connect just fine. Not really sure what the configuration is for the old vs new. I can just work around not having 4.0 for now. Thanks Gary, I'll mark your answer.

Comment: You should not accept this answer as the solution if the answer is unrelated to your solution